# How to get file count of a particular extension in Go?

Tags: go

I am using `ioutil` for iterating a folder:

```golang
existingFiles, err := ioutil.ReadDir(indexPath)
```

I want to get the count of files if they are of type `.txt`. How can I do that without looping? is there any way to pass the pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`filepath.Glob()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob):

```
pattern := filepath.Join(indexPath, "*.txt")
files, err := filepath.Glob(pattern)
if err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("Found %d files.\n", len(files))
}
```

Comment: Lovely and idiomatic